# show that $f(w) = \sum_{i=1}^N (\frac{1}{1+e^{-w^Tx_i}} - t_i)$ is not convex

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-optimization

I am studying logistic regression and in my book it says that using Hessian we can show that $f(w) = \sum_{i=1}^N (\frac{1}{1+e^{-w^Tx_i}} - t_i)$ is not convex. Both $x$ and $t$ are N-Vectors, and $t_i \in \{0,1 \}$. But I dont know how can I show that $min f(w)$ is not a convex optimization problem.

Comment: Have you looked at a graph of $f(w)=1/(1+e^{-w})$?

Comment: @MichaelGrant Yes, Based on the Graph the result is obviuos, But I was wondering how to use hessian for this problem

Comment: OK, but have you computed the Hessian for this scalar case?